# Flutter Firebase Unit Testing

Tags: flutter, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, integration-testing

I've got a project where I've got a load of classes which are used to manipulate data within Firestore. For example:

```
class ExampleClass{
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  
  createObject(){/*...*/}

  editObject(){/*...*/}

  deleteObject(){/*...*/}
  
  /* With more functions for specific data manipulation */
}
```

I'm struggling to find a simple way to run tests on these classes. So far I've run a local Firebase emulator with some dummy test data in it, however to connect to that I've had to run integration tests instead of unit tests.

I don't mind running the local emulator, however the integration tests take a long time to execute and just doesn't feel like the correct way of doing things, seeing as I'm not testing anything UI wise, just the logic.

Is there a better way to quickly run unit tests for classes such as my example which use the local Firestore emulator?

I believe I am essentially asking, is it possible to connect to a local Firestore emulator for unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a Firebase emulator at all to test such classes. Instead I suggest to refactor your classes in such way:

```
class ExampleClass {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore;

  ExampleClass({required FirebaseFirestore store}) : _firestore = store;

  createObject() {/*...*/}

  editObject() {/*...*/}

  deleteObject() {/*...*/}
```

}

Then using [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) or [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) (or any other mocking libraries if they exists) you can easily mock FirebaseFirestore instance which you pass to the constructor in UnitTest and for each call of the method, for example `createObject()` you can verify that corresponding method of FirebaseFirestore is called:

```
  verify(firestoreMock.invokeSomeMethod());
```